# Search box inside slideToggle div won't stay open

Tags: android, jquery, slidetoggle

I have a search box inside a hidden div that slides open when a button is clicked on mobile devices. It works great except for on Android devices. On android when the search input field is touched to bring up the keyboard the div slides closed making it impossible to search.

How can I keep the div open to enable the search box to be used?

Thanks

Here's the jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.search_btn').click(function() {
    $('.search-box').slideToggle('fast');

});

});
```

HTML Markup:

```
<div class="search_btn"><a href="#">Search</a></div>
<div class="search-box">
  <?php get_search_form(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You should really post relevant HTML markup in question

Comment: Sorry, mark up added to the question.